# Mobile client - server communication REST

Tags: android, web-services, rest

I want to develop my own android app which will have to communicate with server. I am quite unexperienced with it so decided to ask some questions.

I read about REST and i think it is good idea to use it for my app. I heard that google, yahoo etc. use it.

Lets say im developing facebook messenger (im obviously not, but it is good example). Is it okay to use REST to communicate with server? Is it secure enough (it is not bank app - it have to guarantee security on facebook messenger level)? And how i can make my server api visible only for app and not for anyone else? Should i use some kind of token? Do i have to hash those messages?

And how those apps get notifications about new messages etc.? Mobile client is just sending REST requests in fixed time intervals (i think it is the only way when using REST?) or is it implemented in some other way?

My server, in principles, will have to deal with huge number of small requests and small responses. Will REST be best for it?